# Conflict between GoogleToolboxForMac & GoogleOpenSource.framework as both contains GTMLogger file

Tags: ios, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-signin, duplicate-symbol, google-toolbox-for-mac

I am getting error :

- ld: 23 duplicate symbols for architecture arm64

&duplicate symbols are found in :

- duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_GTMLogAllowedLevelFilter in:
  /Users/kabloom/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/KaBloom-atezfibugqdtnobedrrypbagrnmn/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/GoogleToolboxForMac/libGoogleToolboxForMac.a(GTMLogger.o)
  /Users/kabloom/Documents/Kabloom/Proj/Current Project/KaBloom Prakash/GoogleOpenSource.framework/GoogleOpenSource(GTMLogger.o)

  I am using latest firebase sdk 4.8.2. I read a lot about the similar question in google forums and few answers here on stack overflow but unable to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I disintegrated Google plus framework and integrated google sign-in with firebase itself. In this way i am able to resolve my problem.